# Substance UI & undecorated JDialog/JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, jdialog, substance

I have noticed that while using the Substance UI for Java that when I set a new JFrame or JDialog to undecorated it is not honored.

e.g.

```
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

When run under Substance shows a decorated frame.

When run under system default L&F shows an undecorated frame.

Anyone have ideas for working around this? I have been unable to find anything on this at the Substance website/java.net forums or already existing in SO.

Comment: Have you tried setting `JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated()` *before* bringing up your the first window?

Comment: the-alchemist, please submit this as an answer so that I can mark it correct and award you the points :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to [The Alchemist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/423943/the-alchemist) for solving my problem:

> Have you tried setting
>   JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated()
>   before bringing up your the first
>   window? – The Alchemist Sep 7 at 12:18

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question, however for anyone who finds this post:

The problem with using,

```
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(false);
```

to fix the undecorated issue, is that it causes ALL of your dialogs to use the default look and feel when they are DECORATED.
If you'd just like one dialog to be undecorated without affecting all the other dialogs, call this on your dialog after setting it undecorated:

```
getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
```